# Programmatically set active session in Zed Attack Proxy

Tags: api, zap

We're working with the `zaproxy` api and we're trying to set a session to "active" with the `setActiveSession()` API-call, which is documented [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiGen_Full) and takes two argument, the `site` and the `session`. The problem we're running into is that we keep getting the error:

```
{
  "code": "illegal_parameter",
  "message": "Provided parameter has illegal or unrecognized value",
  "detail": "session"
}
```

Assuming we have the following sessions from the `sessions()` API-call,

```
{
  "sessions": [
    {
      "session": [
        "Session 1",
        {
          "JSESSIONID": {
            "comment": "",
            "domain": "localhost",
            "domainAttributeSpecified": false,
            "expired": false,
            "expiryDate": null,
            "name": "JSESSIONID",
            "path": "/",
            "pathAttributeSpecified": false,
            "persistent": false,
            "secure": false,
            "value": "941A60311B3C63C69C5887F531E7090A",
            "version": 0
          }
        },
        "16"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What value do we need to send in the `session` field to make this API-call successful? We've tried `value` field in the "complex" `JSESSIONID` object, as well as the name "Session 1" and the "16" (under the assumption that it was an id of some sort), in the `session` array. All of them return the same error.

**[Edit]** I just saw that zap is logging the following into the terminal, when we make these calls:

```
1055328 [ZAP-ProxyThread-106] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API  - ApiException while handling API request:
Provided parameter has illegal or unrecognized value (illegal_parameter) : session
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.httpsessions.HttpSessionsAPI.handleApiAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(Unknown Source)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more trial and error in the API-Browser, we've discovered that the correct value is indeed "Session 1", but we were sending the name in quotations marks, i.e. `"Session 1"`, but the correct way to send it is without them, i.e. `Session 1`.